# Filter Group Based on ID in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to filter out a group of descriptions from a schema based on the IDs in a first schema.

I am very new to Pig so having a hard time getting the hang of this.

Here is the code that I have built which is not working:

```
changeReason = LOAD 'Change_Reason.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('|', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')
    AS (changeReasonID:int, reasonName:chararray);
price = LOAD '$directory/Price.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('|', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')
    AS (priceID:int, changeReasonID:int);

priceChangeReasonIDs = GROUP price BY changeReasonID;
subGroup = FOREACH priceChangeReasonIDs
{
    change = FILTER changeReason BY changeReasonID == group.changeReasonId;
    GENERATE group AS changeID, change.reasonName AS Reason;
};
```

That code gives me the following error:

```
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
<file load_historical_price.pig, line 108, column 20> expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)
```

Comment: Plz. add the input and expected output for the use case

Comment: and also provide the transformedRaw, what you're grouping by PriceChangeReasonId

Comment: Sorry I was taking out proprietary info and that transformedRaw should be price. Changing it now.

Will get the input and output on here later today when I have the files in front of me.

Comment: price has no PriceChangeReasonId field

Comment: Fixed, my search and replace skills failed me big time last night to strip out any identifying data from the library we are using.

Answer (score 0):

May this working example helps:

If I understand it you would like to filter a multi-grouped data by on the the group element.

So here's my example script:

```
data = LOAD 'SO/data.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (val:int, id1:chararray, id2:int);
DESCRIBE data;
dgroup = GROUP data BY (id1, id2);
DESCRIBE dgroup;
dfilter = FILTER dgroup BY group.id1 == 'B';
DESCRIBE dfilter;
DUMP dfilter;
```

This filters the grouped (id1, id2) data by id1.

Example input:

```
12 A 1
22 A 2
32 B 1
33 B 2
43 B 1
55 A 2
77 B 2
88 A 1
```

And the result of the DUMP:

```
((B,1),{(43,B,1),(32,B,1)})
((B,2),{(77,B,2),(33,B,2)})
```

This is what you'd like to do?